# Resolving promises with chai-http respons

Tags: node.js, chai-http

I am very new to NodeJs and trying to run tests. I am trying to return http response from a get call so that I can run assertions on it. SendGetResponse() returns promise and sendResponse awaits this promise to be fulfilled. But I get (node:2152) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined and sendResponse does not wait.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
async sendResponse(){
  this.setUpRequest();
  if (this.verb == 'get'){
    var Promise1 = await this.sendGetRequest();
    console.log("Going to resolve promise");
    console.log(Promise1);
  }
  console.log('Leaving Sendresponse');
  return this.ResponseMessage;
}

sendGetRequest() {
  console.log("In SendGetRequest()");

  const SendRequest = this.GetRequest(this.path,this.headers);
  SendRequest.then(function(res,err){       
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      if (err == null){
        console.log("Resolving promise");
        resolve(res.text);
      }
      else{
        console.log("Rejecting promise");
        reject(err);
      }
    }).catch(error => { 
      console.log('Exception caught', err.message);
    });
  });
}

GetRequest(path,headers){ 
  console.log("In GetRequest()");
  return chai.request(baseurl).get(path).set(headers);
}
```

Comment: Please format the code better, it would be more readable

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`chai` Requests documentation](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-http/#setting-up-requests), it looks like you will need to call `.send()` if setting any HTTP properties like headers or form data. Try the following change to `GetRequest()`:

```
function GetRequest(path, headers) {
  return chai.request(baseUrl)
    .get(path)
    .set(headers)
    .send();
}
```